# Why does dropdown-menu has this wrapping problem?

Tags: drop-down-menu, typo3

My dropdown menu has a little bug: The group of `li`s need be wrapped with a `ul`, but every single `li` now has a `ul` wrapped.

The Typoscript is:

```
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1 = HMENU
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1.special = directory
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1.special.value.data = leveluid:1
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1.wrap = <div class="breadcrumb-nav1">|</div>
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1.1 = TMENU
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1.1 {
  expAll = 1
  noBlur = 1   
  NO.wrapItemAndSub = <ul class="dropdown">|</ul>
  NO.allWrap = <li class="dropdown-item1">|</li>
  ACT = 1
  ACT.allWrap = |
  ACT.ATagParams = class="btn btn-secondary clickme1" style="order:-1;"
}
```

The Output is:

```html
<div class="breadcrumb-nav1">

  <a href="frances.html" class="btn btn-secondary clickme1" style="order:-1;">Francés</a>

  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="dropdown-item1"><a href="ingles.html">Inglés</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="dropdown-item1"><a href="aleman.html">Alemán</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="dropdown-item1"><a href="italiano.html">Italiano</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

But the Output should be:

```html
<div class="breadcrumb-nav1">

  <a href="frances.html" class="btn btn-secondary clickme1" style="order:-1;">Francés</a>

  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="dropdown-item1"><a href="ingles.html">Inglés</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-item1"><a href="aleman.html">Alemán</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-item1"><a href="italiano.html">Italiano</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To achieve the desired structure completely the TypoScript must be different than in my first answer and is more complicated.**
Currently it's not possible to create a link with the function `typolink` and check the `active`-state of it. Therefore below I create the whole menu as `COA` and for the separated active link one HMENU as well as a HMENU for the List of not active items.

```
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1 = COA
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1 {
    wrap = <div class="breadcrumb-nav1">|</div>
    10 = HMENU
    10 {
        special = directory
        special.value.data = leveluid:1
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            expAll = 1
            noBlur = 1 
            NO = 1
            NO.doNotShowLink = 1
            ACT = 1
            ACT.ATagParams = class="btn btn-secondary clickme1" style="order:-1;"
        }
    }
    20 = HMENU
    20 {
        special = directory
        special.value.data = leveluid:1
        wrap = <ul class="dropdown">|</ul>
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            expAll = 1
            noBlur = 1 
            NO.linkWrap = <li class="dropdown-item1">|</li>
            ACT = 1
            ACT.doNotShowLink = 1
        }
    }
}
```

**AFTER EDIT**
... it's tested now, nevertheless let me know if something is not working like expected.

Comment: Great approach. Many thanks for your help!!!!!!
Had to correct a little error (HMENU).
Now, the ACT part does not work. Under 10=HMENU, ACT (active link) does not show. And under 20 = HMENU, the active link appears as normal item (wrapped in li class="dorpdown-item1"). Hmmm, any further suggestions? I think we are getting close....

Answer (score 0):

**This is a workaround or simpler answer, nevertheless it might be useful in some cases. For a solution sticking 100% to the question look at my 2nd answer on this page.**
Concerning Wrapping your challenge is quite a bit difficult, but instead of solving your problem on level of TypoScript, primary I think it's solved already on level of CSS.
So you never need the desired structure but can rely on [CSS property `order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) to get the current language shown in the top.
In detail this means your menu's structure can look like this:

```
<div class="breadcrumb-nav1">
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="dropdown-item1"><a href="ingles.html">Inglés</a></li>
        <li class="btn btn-secondary clickme1" style="order:-1;"><a href="frances.html" >Francés</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item1"><a href="aleman.html">Alemán</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item1"><a href="italiano.html">Italiano</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The the rest is a simple task and you never have to think too much about the TypoScript:

```
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1 = HMENU
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1.special = directory
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1.special.value.data = leveluid:1
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1.wrap = <div class="breadcrumb-nav1">|</div>
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1.1 = TMENU
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1.1 {
  expAll = 1
  noBlur = 1   
  wrap = <ul class="dropdown">|</ul>
  NO.linkWrap = <li class="dropdown-item1">|</li>
  ACT = 1
  ACT.linkWrap = <li class="btn btn-secondary clickme1" style="order:-1;">|</li>
}
```

You still can simplify it now like this, the result should be the same like above:

```
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1 = HMENU
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1.special = directory
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1.special.value.data = leveluid:1
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1.wrap = <div class="breadcrumb-nav1"><ul class="dropdown">|</ul></div>
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1.1 = TMENU
subparts.BREADCRUMBNAV-INTERACTIVE1.1 {
  expAll = 1
  noBlur = 1   
  NO.linkWrap = <li class="dropdown-item1">|</li>
  ACT = 1
  ACT.linkWrap = <li class="btn btn-secondary clickme1" style="order:-1;">|</li>
}
```

For all the wraps you can use for each link, [here is still the reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/Tmenuitem/Index.html), though you probably never need it.

One more thing I remarked is that you seem to use directories to separate languages. If you use the approach to use translations on each page, you can use the common language menu of TYPO3 [which is described here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html#special-language), in general probably you've to substitute only the keyword `directory` by `language`.

Comment: Your solution is actually in place now, but I need to change it and seperate the active link "a" from the group of "li"s (not active), wrapped in an "ul".

Comment: Ok that solution is a bit more complicated, wait a bit. Will post another answer.